# Any way to copy a file from one project to another using 2 different json service keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know I can copy files between projects like this...

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file project1.json
gsutil cp gs://bucket1/file .
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file project2.json
gsutil cp file gs://bucket2/file
```

But this is not good when I want to script it to copy a large amount of files. The `activate-service-account` command will apply to the current linux user so it's not thread safe. Is there any way the above commands can be run in a single command using parameters from `gsutil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any public supported method for `gsutil`. `gcloud` supports configurations which allow you to use different credentials on the command line via `--configuration=CONFIGURATION_NAME`, but `gsutil` does not.

`gsutil` just uses the `default` `gcloud` configuration. When you execute `activate-service-account` you are changing the default configuration to use the new credentials.

There is the undocumented environment variable `CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=CONFIGURATION_NAME` but I do not know if `gsutil` checks this environment variable.

Another undocumented item is that the default configuration is stored in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\active_config` on Windows and `~/.config/gcloud/active_config` on Linux. You might test if `gsutil` is following this convention. This file just stores the configuration `name` for the current default configuration. This means that you will need to setup `gcloud config configurations`. I wrote an article on how to setup configurations:

[Understanding Gcloud Configurations](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/)